# Disable the web browser’s spell check feature on specific Vaadin fields

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Many modern web browsers have a spell-check auto-correction feature that changes a field’s text value.

For some fields, such as "User Name" or "Product Code", this is not good.

Is there a way to disable the web browser’s spell-check feature on individual [fields](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextField.html) in a [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the great [Attributes](https://vaadin.com/addon/attributes) add-on by Michael Vogt to inject the spellcheck attribute to any Vaadin component. Usage:

```
Attribute attribute = new Attribute("spellcheck", "false");
attribute.extend(myTextField);
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Upon further reading I learned this about setting the `spellcheck` attribute: The web browsers consider that attribute to be a request rather than an order. The browser’s defaults or other settings may overrule your request. Better than nothing, but know that setting this attribute is not a sure thing.

Answer (score 0):

## Nope.

No. Vaadin 7.4 and earlier do not yet have a way to programmatically disable a web browser’s [auto-correct spell-check feature](http://caniuse.com/#feat=spellcheck-attribute) on a Vaadin [field](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextField.html).

## Feature Request

[Ticket # 15186](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/15186) has been opened for Vaadin 7 to request "Add the ability to turn on/off spellcheck for text editable components". This ticket is under review as of 2015-03.

## Workaround

As a workaround, see [this forum posting](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/849528) for the possibility of creating a custom component.